# Multiple workspaces do not play well in a dual monitor setup

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, workspaces

At work, I connect my laptop to a second monitor and use 4 workspaces. When I disconnect the second monitor, the windows open in different workspaces get jumbled up; eg. a bunch of terminal windows opened in workspace 3 will appear in workspace 1 once I unplug the monitor. Is this a known bug? I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: When I unplug an external monitor I like it when the windows there go to the connected display (internal in my laptop's scenario). Where should those windows go if not to the connected one?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Obviously I would want all the windows in the secondary monitor to jump to the primary display once I disconnect the former. My problem is that some random windows jump to a random workspace, and I have to sit and rearrange all the windows all over again.

Comment: This is starting to sound like a new feature request where you want new windows from disconnected display to be minimized or underneath existing windows?